# What does up arrow ($\uparrow$) mean in pseudocode?

Tags: notation

I'm learning vantage point trees, and I met this while reading the paper *Data Structures and Algorithms for Nearest Neighbor Search in General Metric Spaces* by Peter Yianilos (*Proceedings of SODA 1993*, SIAM, pages 311–321; [PDF](http://pnylab.com/pny/papers/vptree/vptree.pdf)).  The following pseudocode appears in Algorithm 1.

$$\begin{align*}
\hspace{2em}&\hspace{-2em}
\textbf{function}\text{ Make_vp_tree(}S\text{)}\\
&\textbf{if }S=\emptyset\textbf{ then return }\emptyset\\
&\text{new(node);}\\
&\text{node}\!\uparrow\!\!\text{.p} := \text{Select_vp(}S\text{);}\\
&\text{node}\!\uparrow\!\!\text{.mu} := \text{Median}_{s\in S}\, d(p,s);\\
&\dotsc
\end{align*}$$

`node` is a node of vp-tree, so I know what `node.p` means, but what do that up arrow means in this context?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The algorithms in the paper you link to are described in a notation quite similar to Pascal, a language that treats pointers in a very particular way. In Pascal, pointers are declared as references to values of specific types (a pointer to an integer can never refer to a boolean, for instance).

The upward arrow, in the example you reproduce, is a dereferencing operator. Clearly, `node` is a *pointer* to a value of a record type (not a record itself), of which `p` and `mu` are fields, so `node.p` has no meaning.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9353824/4909871) similar question for further clarification.